# Trying to switch screens when player dies in visual studio using xaml

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

When the player dies the game currently exits but I want it to display MainMenu.xaml
It's currently as follows:

```
public void onPlayerDeath(){

    game.Exit();
}
```

What is a way to make it go to the main menu.xaml frame instead of game.Exit?

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of your MainMenu window and show it.

```
public void onPlayerDeath()
{
    MainMenu mm = new mainMenu();
    mm.Show();
}
```